# proof that $E(K) \leq \frac{1}{2}V(K)(V(K)-1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $K$ be a connected compact surface that has a triangulation
and $V(K)$ be the number of verticals, $E(K)$ be the number of edges.
Prove that:
$$
E(K) \leq \frac{1}{2}V(K)(V(K)-1)
$$
Thank you any help

Comment: It might help to know that $n(n-1)/2 = \binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: you mean n(n-1)/2 = n/2 or what thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient